# I need to optimize a function, which uses unique_ptr and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, optimization, c++14, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

So, I have been working on my assignment for quite a while but stumbled upon a problem that I couldn't solve by myself.

My task was to create a class `CompositeShape` which would be capable of holding `shared_ptr` pointers of a base class `Shape` in a `unique_ptr` array so that we would then have an array of derived from `Shape` classes. The `CompositeShape` by itself is derived from `Shape` as well.

So, even though the code below works fine and even provides a strong exception guarantee, my teacher says that this particular function can be optimized.

```
void kosnitskiy::CompositeShape::add(const std::shared_ptr<Shape> &src)
{
  if (src == nullptr)
  {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Attempt to add an empty pointer exception");
  }
  std::unique_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Shape>[]> shapes(new std::shared_ptr<Shape>[count_ + 1]);
  for (int i = 0; i < count_; i++)
  {
    shapes[i] = std::move(shapes_[i]);
  }
  shapes[count_] = src;
  shapes_ = std::move(shapes);
  count_ += 1;
}
```

My first reaction was to change the array expanding algorithm to something similar to a `vector` one so that we wouldn't be forced to create a new array every time a new element is being added, but the teacher said, that despite the fact it's a quite good idea, he talks about the different type of improvement. The one, which wouldn't change the class design. So I assume there is a flaw somewhere in a function itself. I have already changed the assignment construction, used in a `for` loop, from `shapes[i] = shapes_[i]`  to a one using the `std::move` instead, since I figured that move assignment operator would be way more efficient than a copy assignment one, but I'm pretty much out of ideas now.

I'm not allowed to make any class design changes. I didn't use `vector` because it was specified by the teacher that we can't use any standard containers. I didn't use `weak_ptr` for the same reason as well: we were told only to use `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` pointers. Non-smart pointers are blocked as well

Thank you very much for your help in advance

Comment: *"holding `shared_ptr` pointers in a `unique_ptr` array"* Why? That makes no sense. Most likely, you want `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>>` - a vector of shared pointers. Then `add` would be as simple as `shapes_.push_back(src)`

Comment: Note that if you have a composite that contains element containing the composite itself, using a shared_pointer is probably dangerous (weak_ptr should be used instead because of cycles). However, I do not know if this is possible in your case.

Comment: I completely agree with both of your answers, but I can't use either of them, since I'm not allowed to make any class design changes. I didn't use `vector` because it was specified by the teacher, that we can't use any standard containers. I didn't use `weak_ptr` for the same reason as well: we were told only to use `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`. Non smart pointers are blocked as well

Comment: Your teacher is being childish. You say "this function is quite inefficient in very obvious ways, let me fix it", and they are like "yeah, that's all well and good, but set that aside and guess what tiny tweak I'm thinking of". For what it's worth, I don't see any such small improvements either.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that teacher's remark might about passing `src` by value and moving it into the array.
Another option would be to use `std::move` with `std::begin/end` instead of a raw `for` loop.
But both of those seem to be micro-optimizations with the array growing by 1 and being reallocated with each addition and are out of context.